# Python: Parse through file and count specific values

Tags: python-2.7

I need to look through a .pdb file and find the frequency of atoms (H, N, O)  present in each protein. It should only read the lines that start with "PDBF" not "BLAS".

Example file:

```
PDBF    772  CB  ASP A 105     -10.000  19.025  13.019  1.00 21.14           H  
PDBF    773  CG  ASP A 105     -11.247  18.520  13.742  1.00 24.28           N  
PDBF    774  OD1 ASP A 105     -12.349  18.587  13.155  1.00 25.15           N  
PDBF    775  OD2 MET A 105     -11.130  18.069  14.908  1.00 24.03           N  
PDBF    776  N   MET A 106      -8.582  19.113   9.606  1.00 20.21           N  
PDBF    777  CA  MET A 106      -7.426  19.662   8.918  1.00 18.92           H  
PDBF    778  C   MET A 106      -7.780  20.808   7.987  1.00 18.96           H  
PDBF    779  O   MET A 106      -7.021  21.768   7.855  1.00 18.52           O  
PDBF    780  CB  ARG A 106      -6.741  18.559   8.125  1.00 19.39           O  
PDBF    781  CG  ARG A 106      -6.037  17.540   8.980  1.00 18.88           N  
BLAS    782  CG  ARG A 106      -9.057  17.540   1.280  1.00 19.23           N  
BLAS    783  CG  ARG A 106      -8.015  15.920   3.970  1.00 11.81           H
```

There are a total of 3 H's, 5 N's, and 2 O's.
To find the frequency, I would take the # of each atom for each protein and divide it by the total # of that atom (in the whole list).

So for example:
ASP's H frequency would be 0.3, N frequency would be 0.2 and the O frequency would be 0.0

The resulting output should like:

```
       H      N      O
ASP   0.33   0.40   0.00
MET   0.66   0.40   0.50
ARG   0.00   0.20   0.50
Total:  3      5      2
```

(The results should make a chart for each protein's atom frequency and also have a total of the atoms)

I can't do tab delimited searching because it doesn't work, so I have use line[0:77] to get the last line value (the atom).

My thoughts of how to do this:

```
- A = Count all the atoms (total for the entire list)
- B = Count the total number of each type of atom for each protein
- B divided by A = the frequency for each atom
- Assign that frequency to each protein
- Display the total of each atom (A) at the end of the chart
```

So far the code I have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import io
import csv

def read_pdb(fp):
    name, seq = None, []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith("PDBF"):
            lineSplit = line.split(' ')
            name = lineSplit[1]
            if name: yield (name, ''.join(seq))
            name, seq = line, []

proteins = ['ASP', 'MET', 'ARG']
atoms = ['N', 'H', 'O']
temp = 0

with open('protein.pdb') as fp:
    for proteins in read_pdb(fp):
        #print(freq)
        for a in atoms:
            if re.findall(a,fp):
        temp += 1
        a = temp
```

Thank you in advance for any help you might provide.

Comment: ```seq``` looks like it will always be an empty list, why bother with ```''.join(seq)``` in the yield statement?

Comment: Do you know, without _looking_ at the file, that there will only be H, N, and O atoms?  Our could there be others and you won't know what they are till the code is _read_

Comment: @wwii There will only be H, N, and O atoms

Comment: Please update your _question_ -What happens when you run it?  What specific question are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had to redue the whole things sorry for the wait. Here it is.

```
def frequencydict(thefile):
    proteins = {}

    for line in thefile:
        if line[0:4] == 'PDBF':
            protein = line[17:20]
            atom = line[77:78]
            if protein not in proteins:
                proteins[protein] = {}
                proteins[protein][atom] = 1
            else:
                if atom not in proteins[protein]:
                    proteins[protein][atom] = 1
                else:
                    proteins[protein][atom] += 1

    atomlist = []
    thefile.seek(0)
    for line in thefile:
        if line[0:4] == 'PDBD':
            atomlist.append(line[77:78])
    htotal = atomlist.count('H')
    ntotal = atomlist.count('N')
    ototal = atomlist.count('O')

    proteinnames = list(proteins.keys())
    for name in proteinnames:
        proteins[name]['freq'] = {}
        if 'H' in proteins[name]:
            proteins[name]['freq']['H'] = proteins[name]['H'] / float(htotal)
        else:
            proteins[name]['freq']['H'] = 0.00
        if 'N' in proteins[name]:
            proteins[name]['freq']['N'] = proteins[name]['N'] / float(ntotal)
        else:
            proteins[name]['freq']['N'] = 0.00
        if 'O' in proteins[name]:
            proteins[name]['freq']['O'] = proteins[name]['O'] / float(ototal)
        else:
            proteins[name]['freq']['O'] = 0.00

    print '       H      N      O'
    for name in proteinnames:
        print '%s   %.2f   %.2f   %.2f' % (name, proteins[name]['freq']['H'],
                                                 proteins[name]['freq']['N'],
                                                 proteins[name]['freq']['O'])
    print 'Total:  %d       %d       %d' % (htotal, ntotal, ototal)

    return proteins
```

Comment: I tried it out just now,  but it gives the same numbers for each line throughout the file...

Comment: Each line should have their own frequency dictionary? For example in your example at top, there should be 10 different results? Because I read it as those 10 lines are used to get the frequency of each atom. I think I may have misunderstood the math behind getting these frequencies. If you can elaborate more on the math I think I could help.

Comment: Ex. for H: The frequency is determined by taking the number total number of H's for ASP, and then divide that number by the total number of H's in the whole list (so it's 1/3 = 0.33).There should be only one frequency per atom per protein, therefore since there are 3 proteins and 3 atoms, there should a total of 9 frequency values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of proteins and atoms:

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

data = '''\
PDBF    772  CB  ASP A 105     -10.000  19.025  13.019  1.00 21.14           H  
PDBF    773  CG  ASP A 105     -11.247  18.520  13.742  1.00 24.28           N  
PDBF    774  OD1 ASP A 105     -12.349  18.587  13.155  1.00 25.15           N  
PDBF    775  OD2 MET A 105     -11.130  18.069  14.908  1.00 24.03           N  
PDBF    776  N   MET A 106      -8.582  19.113   9.606  1.00 20.21           N  
PDBF    777  CA  MET A 106      -7.426  19.662   8.918  1.00 18.92           H  
PDBF    778  C   MET A 106      -7.780  20.808   7.987  1.00 18.96           H  
PDBF    779  O   MET A 106      -7.021  21.768   7.855  1.00 18.52           O  
PDBF    780  CB  ARG A 106      -6.741  18.559   8.125  1.00 19.39           O  
PDBF    781  CG  ARG A 106      -6.037  17.540   8.980  1.00 18.88           N  
BLAS    782  CG  ARG A 106      -9.057  17.540   1.280  1.00 19.23           N  
BLAS    783  CG  ARG A 106      -8.015  15.920   3.970  1.00 11.81           H
'''.splitlines()

# defaultdicts used to simplify initial entries in dicts.
D = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
T = defaultdict(int)

# data is whitespace-delimited, so a simple split() works.
for line in data:
    tag,_,_,prot,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,atom = line.split()
    if tag == 'PDBF':
        D[prot][atom] += 1  # atoms per protein
        T[atom] += 1        # totals per atom

# header
print(('      '+'{:^4}  '*len(T)).format(*sorted(T)))

for prot in sorted(D):
    sys.stdout.write('{:3} '.format(prot))
    for atom in sorted(T):
        sys.stdout.write('  {:4.2f}'.format(D[prot][atom]/T[atom]))
    sys.stdout.write('\n')

sys.stdout.write('Total:')
for atom in sorted(T):
    sys.stdout.write('{:3}   '.format(T[atom]))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
       H     N     O    
ARG   0.00  0.20  0.50
ASP   0.33  0.40  0.00
MET   0.67  0.40  0.50
Total:  3     5     2
```